# Has meetup.com removed support for RSVP buttons?

Tags: meetup

I used to get the code to embed `RSVP` button for any meetup from here: https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/buttons/. Seems like that page no longer exists. Does anyone know if they have removed support for it?

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They no longer support those buttons. 
Instead they now have these widgets, which promotes the upcoming event in your meetup. 
[You can find the widgets here.](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/foundry/)